# If $A$ is null set, then $\int\limits_A f dm = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Define $ \int_E f dm = \sup Y(E, f) $

where $ Y(E,f) = \{ \int_E \phi : 0 \leq \phi \leq f \} $ $\phi$ is simple

Suppose $A$ is a null set. We show $Y(A, f) = \{ 0 \}$. Pick $x \in Y(A, f)$. So, we have $x = \int_A \phi dm $ for some simple $\phi \leq f$. Let $\phi = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i 1_{A_i} $.

$$ \therefore \int\limits_A \phi = \sum a_i m(A \cap A_i) \leq \sum a_i m(A) = 0 \implies \int\limits_A \phi = 0$$

Therefore, $Y(A,f) \subseteq \{ 0 \} $.
How can we show that $\{ 0 \} $ is in $Y(A,f) $ ? Or can we just assume this since the integral is never negative so it must be at least $0$, and hence the singleton $0$ must be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $f\geq 0$ (it seems that you are assuming this), it should be obvious that $0\in Y(E,f)$.  Let $\phi\equiv 0$: then $\phi$ is simple, $0\leq\phi\leq f$, and $\int_E \phi=0$.